# C++: Creating array index larger than size not causing error

Tags: c++, arrays

I am learning C++ and as I understand it an array should not populate if you try to assign a value to it that is invalid due to the size restriction placed on the array, yet the following code is properly outputting 232:

```
int stuff[5];
stuff[7] = 232;
cout<<stuff[7];
```

I'm sorry if this is an incredibly stupid question, but is this just something my compiler is patching up before run-time?

Comment: This is like saying, "Look, I *can* hold the ball in my hands" in basketball.

Comment: More like "I had my driver's license revoked, so why am I able to get into a car and drive it?"

Comment: It's like a player in a basketball saying "Look, I can hold the ball in my hands" and then deciding whether he gets to keep playing that way based on the locations of the other players.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing outside the bounds of an array is undefined behavior, which means the results could be anything.  In particular, the compiler is not required to add any run-time bounds-checking that would cause an error message to be emitted (and most compilers don't, since it's more efficient not to).

So what's likely happening is that the value is being written to a memory location just past the end of the array.  If something important was stored there, something bad will happen; or if whatever happened to be at that location was not so important, you won't notice any particular effect.  You can't rely on on it being harmless, though, so don't do that. :)

Comment: Perfect, this is the answer I needed.  I wasn't satisfied with the other, more vague answer.

Comment: Is there a way to see or even control the exact "location" within the memory something will be allocated to?

Comment: Well, there's placement-new, but you don't want to use it unless you really know what you're doing.  In general the compiler will do a much better and more reliable job of placing things in an appropriate spot than a human will.  Trying to do its job for it will only make both it and you unhappy.  ;)

Comment: @JS: You can see/control the location by viewing/changing a pointer, but that is much less useful these days then before.  One use of that is writing to memory mapped registers of interfacing hardware. Another may be debugging (checking location)

Comment: Cool, I'm one or two chapters out from pointers in the book I'm going through!

Comment: @JS No, undefined behavior is undefined. Nothing is guaranteed if you do this. And your intuition is wrong.

Comment: I recognize that based on his response.  Is it just me or are you always being a prick when I see you?  Perhaps your efforts would be more constructive if they weren't exhausted downvoting legitimate questions, attacking people on comment threads, and making (likely false) assumptions of my intuition.

Comment: @JS It's just you. I wasn't attacking you in any way. I don't know why telling you that your intuition is wrong counts as an attack when your intuition is clearly wrong.

Comment: So tell me then, what is my intuition?

Answer (score 2):

Accessing an array out of bounds results in undefined behaviour. It might work, it might give the wrong answer, it might crash the program, whatever.

Comment: What decides what the result is?  Compiler? Operating system? Hardware?

Comment: Yes to both. Also luck.

Comment: @Adam Such confidence. :P